# Invalid token in class struct or interface member declaration in c#

Tags: c#, class, struct, token

I have searched for this, but I can't seem to fix my code still.

I am learning C# and watching a tutorial, my code is identical to the video, but I get errors, when the video code works perfect, can anyone see anything wrong with my code?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 if that makes any difference at all.

All it does is call in a file, read it and display the text in a Console window.

I get the following errors:
Invalid token '(' in class struct or interface member declaration
Invalid token '=' in class struct or interface member declaration
Invalid token '{' in class struct or interface member declaration

Error   10  'ConsoleApplication4.Program.inpFile' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

Thanks for any help,
Adam
P.S - Sorry for being such a newb...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LoadFile();
        }
        private static void LoadFile();
    {
        StreamReader inpFile = null;
        inpFile = File.OpenText("../../well.txt")
        Console.WriteLine(inpFile.ReadToEnd());
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: You have a semi-colon at the end of the `LoadFile();` method declaration. That's why the method body is outdented, too... always look for the indentation as a clue as to where things are wrong. I doubt that the code in the video has that semi-colon, so it's not really identical...

Comment: You are right, it's not identical, my bad. Thank You.

Comment: I suggest you delete the question - typo questions like this don't have long term value IMO.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the following lines:

```
private static void LoadFile();


inpFile = File.OpenText("../../well.txt")
```

write:

```
 private static void LoadFile()
 inpFile = File.OpenText("../../well.txt");
```